# how to make keybind press and not pressed

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

Hi I'm a beginner at java I'm having this error idk how to solve it

```java
if (item.getItem() instanceof net.minecraft.item.ItemBlock) {
    mc.gameSettings.keyBindSneak.pressed = false;
    BlockPos BlockPos = new BlockPos(this.mc.thePlayer.posX, this.mc.thePlayer.posY - 1.0 D, this.mc.thePlayer.posZ);
    if (this.mc.theWorld.getBlockState(BlockPos).getBlock() == Blocks.air) {
        this.mc.gameSettings.keyBindSneak.pressed = true;
    } else if (this.mc.theWorld.getBlockState(BlockPos).getBlock() == Blocks.air) {}

}
```

I'm trying to make the player sneak and not sneaking in specific events

Comment: What version of Forge are you using, and for what Minecraft version?

Comment: Minecraft java 1.8.9 and forge 1.8.9 latest version

Comment: Okay, and what error are you getting? (edit the question to add it)